# Best Practices: how to design Page Object test suites for multiple similar web sites

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, minitest, pageobjects

I'm starting to re-design all my test suites with the Page-Object model, but, every documentation or tutorial I've found show examples in single-site projects, and in my case, I have like 10 or more sites (and the list is growing, next year there will be like 20 or 30 sites) that share near 90% of the UI elements and data, and other sites that share like 50-80% of the UI elements and data. Also, the sites have mobile versions that have somewhat different UI elements from the Desktop versions, say they are 80% similar than the Desktop versions.

What is the best approach to design something with this scenario in mind? Should I design it like to have a different Page-Object class for every site and for Desktop/mobile versions? or should I group them in Desktop and Mobile versions respectively naming the elements with the prefix name of the Site? I cannot seem to found any standard for situations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Page Object Model, you should ideally have 1 class for each screen/page which encapsulates all your objects and methods within that page.
Create a new page class for each screen. I would suggest have an abstract class for each page (with all the common say 90% objects defines ) and make sure your methods are overridable from the child classes. There can be multiple child classes of each page object abstarct class (eg different technologies Modile/Desktop) where you can override any method that doesnt use the common abstract method in that particular technology. 
Maintain separate object classes(per page) which will maintain properties of all your objects in that page. To read more on page objects model visit:

http://testautomationlove.blogspot.in/2016/02/page-object-design-pattern.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Nearly a week ago i come to the very same conclution and begin to code in this way, a class that has the most common elements and methods for every page on the sites and then to extend those classes with the different sites with their respective changes. Very happy now to get to the same conclution! Thank you very much!

Comment: glad it was of help :)